# Nuxt/Content surround for previous and next

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I cannot retrive prev and next article with nuxt content.

in my slug page I have this code:

```js
async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
  const article = await $content('onstep', params.slug).fetch();

  const [prev, next] = await $content('onstep')
    .only(['title', 'slug', 'order'])
    .sortBy('order', 'desc')
    .surround(params.slug)
    .fetch();

  return {
    article,
    prev,
    next
  };
},
```

but prev and next returning null, oneother things I don't understand, is the

```js
.surround(params.slug)
```

Why is used params.slug???

If I use postman to `http://localhost:3000/_content/onstep?only=title&only=slug&only=order` I get the list of my article, in my case I use a tag called order to order how the content should be seen.

In my project I need to use `trailingSlash` to `true`, but if I console.log params.slug is without `trailingSlash`

any suggestions?

Comment: Params should not include any trailing slash so far. You're maybe looking for `this.$route.path`? Also, do you have a [repro] for this one?

Comment: if I use ` this.$route.path ` I get error Unexpected this in asyncData,I have no idea how and where I can send you a minimal example project.
The strange thing I seen, If I remove surround method I get the list of all articles as I expected...

Comment: If you're using `asyncData`, you need to use the context, hence writing it this way: `  asyncData({ route }) {`. For a minimal project, either share your github repo or create a new project reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

my fault, and one day gone...

Having some problems with google crawler I addes the / to any slug, so nuxt will try to find my-slug but in all articles the slug are my-slug/ edited all the slug and now work perfectly